# Random values in fixed interval - how to assign probability distribution?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-entropy

Please excuse my lack of terminology. I am just a humble discrete optimizer

Assume we have a kind of "coin toss" where the result is not binary, but a rational number between -1 and 1. There is nothing known a priori about the probability distribution underlying this "coin".

What can I do to estimate the probability distribution through experiments?

I read a bit about Bayesian and Maximum Entropy approaches, but I need somebody to guide me in the right direction.

Comment: What was wrong with Benoit's answer? I mean, there is a huge literature on non-parametric statistics when it comes to bandwidth selection, etc.  e.g. Take for example `R`, `density`, set the `bw` to `SJ` and cite Sheather & Jones, 1991, JRSS B. JRSS B is definitely not *found by "experience"* (it can an *experience to read* but that a different story). Most smoothing papers provide Asymptotic convergence, etc. so they have solid theoretical foundations.

Comment: Maybe it is just my lack of understanding. Could somebody elaborate how you would choose the bandwith in my scenario (and why you do it that way)?

Comment: Hmm.. to save having to scavenge old JASA/JRSS B paper check David Scott's Chapter on *Multivariate Density Estimation and Visualization* from the *Handbook of Computational Statistics* editors:  Gentle, Härdle & Mori. It has an aptly named section "*A High-Level View of Density Theory*" that will be helpful. Larry Wasserman's "*All of Nonparametric* Statistics" has two chapters (#5 & 6) on "*Non-parametric regression*" and "*Density Estimation*" that can be very helpful too.

Comment: You write "a rational number between -1 and 1" do you really mean rational (i.e. quotient of two signed integers) or are real numbers (such as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ also possible?

Comment: It definitely would also help to explain what type of answer you are looking for. What do you mean by "finding a probability distribution"? If this is too theoretical, maybe try to explain what would be wrong about simply taking the empirical cdf of a (large) number of experiments.

Comment: @gg 1. I really mean rational, but I guess that doesn't make a difference for the probability distribution. 2. The empirical cdf seems to be one possible solution. What I really need is a convincing line of argumentation (a "proof" would be great) that leads from my setup to a probability distribution. So if I get a sequence of experimental results (like 0.4, -0.3, 0.2, 0.23), I can say: "In the absence of any further information, this leads to the probability distribution ..."

Answer (score 4):

If I understand what you mean, you don't have an a priori about the family  (normal, Beta...) the distribution belongs to. This is called a non parametric approach.

A simple method to estimate a distribution is [kernel density estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).

You can also use Maximum Entropy but then you implicitly assume a certain family. You have to:

- define a few properties of the distribution you estimate empirically (like expectation, expectation of the log, expectation of the square, variance...)
- Take the distribution matching these properties that has maximum entropy.

With this method, defining the properties you want to estimate is equivalent to choosing a distribution family. For example, if you choose mean and variance (assume your values range over $]-\infty;\infty[$), then the distribution will be a normal distribution.

Kernel density estimator is maybe closer to the idea of having no a priori.

Comment: Thank you. If I try kernel density estimators, this leaves me with the question of choosing a kernel and a bandwith. How do I get to a "scientifically justified" choice of these parameters? Any good literature about that?

Comment: A Gaussian kernel is the usual choice. The Wikipedia article suggest a "rule of thumb" bandwidth estimator that automatically adapts to the statistical power of you dataset. It works well.

Comment: Thanks again. This is indeed useful. But it would be great to have some kind of (theoretical) justification for the choice of kernel and bandwidth, so that I could convince other people that the probability distribution I propose is indeed the "right" (most plausible) one.

Comment: It's not the most plausible one. It's only somehow the smoothest one (adapted to visualization...). I don't think there is a definition to of a most plausible one, except with Bayesian analysis. But the prior is extremely complex here (a distribution on any distribution) and 100% subjective. With MaxENT, you get the most "plausible" one (in Jayne's way of seeing things), but again the choice of the properties you estimate is subjective.

Answer (score 1):

> There is nothing known a priori about the probability distribution underlying this "coin".

Do you have no information at all about the source that produces this information? If you know something about the nature of the process, you could choose a type of distribution and then fit the model by finding the maximum likelihood estimation for the parameters.

If there is really no a priori information available about the type of distribution, the best estimate that you can get is an empirical histogram or kernel density estimate. Both the histogram and the kernel density estimate have parameters that determine how the estimate will look like. For the histogram this is the bin width, and for the kernel density estimate this is bandwidth parameter. [Elements of Density Estimation](https://www.math.utah.edu/~davar/math6070/2014/DensityEstimation.pdf) by the Utah university provides a good overview of those methods.

If the bandwidth or bin width is chosen too low, the estimate will be too coarse. If the bandwidth is too narrow, you might overfit the model if you have too little data, as can be seen in [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#/media/File:Comparison_of_1D_bandwidth_selectors.png) from the KDE wikipedia page. In general, the more data is available, the narrower you can set the bandwith parameter. Chapter 3 of the Utah paper talks about optimal bandwidth selection.

How good your estimate will be all depends on the number of samples that you can get from your source, and from the distribution itself. For example, when estimating a histogram bin with an estimated probability of one in a hundred, you need well over a hundred samples to be certain that the probability is actually one in a hundred. A simple test that you could do is to divide your data up in to multiple sets, and then compute the histogram or KDE for each set. If the variance of the different estimates is within a reasonable boundary, you can use this of a proof that is a good estimate. Once again, the Utah paper provides some nice background about this problem.